# ViewController Transition notifications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

Is there a way to track UIViewController transitions?  As part of analytics, I would like to measure how long the user spends in each UIViewController without adding the code to all the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You could add notifications on the controller's push methods and register to listen for them in the application delegate.

But I don't know how you would do that without adding code to the controllers, as that is usually where push methods are kept.